# Why does my routing setup /:id and /route not work in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes

In my app I have 2 routes:

```typescript
/employees/{id}
/employees/new
```

I tried to attach components to the routes in my ROUTING array the following way:

```typescript
export const ROUTES: Routes = 
[...,
  {
   path: 'employees/:id',
   component: ViewEmployeeComponent
  },
  {
   path: 'employees/new',
   component: NewEmployeeComponent,
   pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]
```

The `view` variant works but when I try to navigate to `employees/new`, the corresponding component is not loaded and a 404 page not found exception is thrown.

How can I use both those routing paths within Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to swap that two routes like bellow

```typescript
    {
      path: 'employees/new',
      component: NewEmployeeComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'employees/:id',
        component: ViewEmployeeComponent
    }
```

Also keep this in mind

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by
>   design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching
>   routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific
>   routes.

You could able to find more details from their [DOC](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more code (how are you navigating for example)

Anyway, the optimal way for navigating between such routes is by children routes approach.
Please follow the following link: 
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/routing/child_routes

Comment: You cannot use this approach if you want a `/create` route, because you do not know the id of the new object yet.